# What is the action done on an array when this statement is executed in C programing ++arrayname[value[i]/10];

Tags: c, arrays, increment, operator-keyword

Here i just want to know what is the action done when using this increment operator in this statement.
What does it mean to use an increment operator before an array?

Comment: well it increments element at position value[i]/10 in arrayname (and the one that wrote this hates you)

Comment: Push this into a text editor, compile it with a c compiler and execute the code. You will know it. QED!

Answer (score 0):

The same thing it means anywhere else: increment the thing that comes after it.

Here, that thing is `arrayname[value[i]/10]`, i.e. the `value[i]/10`<sup>th</sup> element of `arrayname`.

```
int array[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };  // Array has: 0, 1, 2, 3
++array[0];                    // Array has: 1, 1, 2, 3
```